# How does empty cts:and-query do in terms of performance

Tags: marklogic

Suppose,I have a bunch of medical journals with root elements as medicalJournal.All medical journals belong in the 'mj' collection, and 'mj' collection has only medical journals. Journals of other types too have their own collections(physicsJournal->'pj')
To retrieve all medical journals I write the simplest query in the world:

```
cts:search(/medicalJournal,cts:and-query(()))
```

However, a peer of mine says why not put a collection query against 'pj' instead of the empty and query,and thus add an extra constraint.A rationale is that, this might avoid fetching of list of all fragment ids that the empty-and does.Although when I ran the collection query the first time ,the query meter showed some list-cache-misses. 
Please let me know which option should be taken?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that `cts:and-query(())` has no inherent cost, but a collection query would be faster than your searchable expression. I'd avoid using a searchable expression at all, so I'd write this as:

```
cts:search(collection(), cts:collection-query($journal-collection))
```

The longer answer is that your can test this pretty easily, and get some good information from `xdmp:plan` and 'xdmp:query-meters`. You could also use query profiling.

Let's start by inserting some test documents. This uses https://github.com/mblakele/taskbot

```
(: insert 500k test documents. :)
import module namespace tb="ns://blakeley.com/taskbot"
  at "taskbot.xqm" ;

tb:list-segment-process(
  (: Total size of the job. :)
  1 to 500 * 1000,
  (: Size of each segment of work. :)
  500,
  "test/asset",
  (: This anonymous function will be called for each segment. :)
  function($list as item()+, $opts as map:map?) {
    (: Any chainsaw should have a safety. Check it here. :)
    tb:maybe-fatal(),
    let $type-list := ('mj', 'pj', 'aj', 'bj', 'cj', 'dj')
    let $type-count := count($type-list)
    for $i in $list
    let $idx := 1 + xdmp:random($type-count - 1)
    let $type as xs:string := subsequence($type-list, $idx, 1)
    return xdmp:document-insert(
      "test/"||$type||"/"||$i,
      element article {
        element id { $type||$i },
        element type { $type },
        element { $type } { $i },
        element issue { 1 + xdmp:random(99) },
        element article { 1 + xdmp:random(999) },
        (1 to xdmp:random(9)) ! element article-ref {
          xdmp:random(1000) } },
      xdmp:default-permissions(),
      ($type)),
    (: This is an update, so be sure to commit each segment. :)
    xdmp:commit() },
  (: options - not used in this example. :)
  map:new(map:entry('testing', '123...')),
  (: This is an update, so be sure to say so. :)
  $tb:OPTIONS-UPDATE)
```

Sit back and wait for the documents to load. You can check `ErrorLog.txt` to see progress, or refresh the database status. Or just watch your CPUs.

Once loaded, these test documents include a lot of redundancy. This lets us test different ways to retrieve documents. Here's a sample to look at:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
  <id>mj192462</id>
  <type>mj</type>
  <mj>192462</mj>
  <issue>31</issue>
  <article>432</article>
  <article-ref>589</article-ref>
  <article-ref>812</article-ref>
  <article-ref>316</article-ref>
  <article-ref>512</article-ref>
  <article-ref>380</article-ref>
</article>
```

Now, I prefer to leave the first `cts:search` parameter as `collection()` and do everything in the cts:query parameter. It's more composable and avoids any temptation to push the boundaries of searchable expressions. So I'd start by testing that `cts:search(//mj, cts:and-query(()))` is equivalent to `cts:search(collection(), cts:element-query(xs:QName('mj'), cts:and-query(())))`. Using 7.0-4.1 and `xdmp:plan` I see that they both use the same lookup, which we might abbreviate as `OR(element(mj), link-child(descendant(element(mj))))`.

```
<qry:final-plan>
  <qry:and-query>
    <qry:or-two-queries>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>213142789040258053</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>element(mj)</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
        <qry:key>11205365121816230941</qry:key>
        <qry:annotation>link-child(descendant(element(mj)))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
    </qry:or-two-queries>
  </qry:and-query>
</qry:final-plan>
```

Notice how there isn't anything in the plan corresponding to your `cts:and-query(())`? That's because it's a noop. The real work in a query like `cts:search(/medicalJournal, cts:and-query(()))` is done by processing the searchable expression `/medicalJournal`. That might help explain why I prefer to leave the searchable expression as `collection()` and match using the `cts:query` parameter.

The `link-child` term is interesting, but let's not go into it now.

Instead let's look at some other ways to get to `mj` articles. We could query on collection `mj`, or elements where `type[.='mj']`, or a directory query on `test/mj/`.

```
collection('mj')

cts:search(collection(), cts:collection-query('mj'))

cts:search(collection(), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('type'), 'mj')

cts:search(collection(), cts:directory-query('test/mj/', 'infinity'))
```

Checking the `xdmp:plan` output for each, we see that the `qry:final-plan` shows two `term-query` lookups for the first two forms. This looks much like the `element-query` on `mj` did - but not always the same terms. Then we see one each for the last three. Term lookups drive query complexity, so we can say that the element query is twice as complex as the collection query.

That pretty much answers your question, I think: `cts:search(collection(), cts:collection-query('mj'))` can be faster than `cts:search(collection(), cts:element-query(xs:QName('mj'), cts:and-query(())))`, because it does fewer term lookups.

But let's keep going with the last three and see if there's any reason to use one or the other of those last three alteratives. The collection lookup and the directory lookup both use URIs: respectively, collection URIs and directory URIs. Those are pretty heavily optimized, so we might expect them to be faster than an element-value lookup.

Let's see if we can prove that, using `xdmp:query-meters`. Run each of the last three expressions in a form like this:

```
xdmp:describe(
  cts:search(collection(), cts:collection-query('mj')))
, xdmp:query-meters()
```

For this exercise focus on what `xdmp:query-meters` says about tree cache and list cache hits and misses. Don't pay too much attention to `elapsed-time`, because that will depend quite a bit on how much of the index data is cached and we can't control that. Anyway you should see the same total tree hits and misses with all three queries. I saw 9 for each, but the important thing is that there's no difference because the results are the same. But the list cache hits and misses total up differently. With collection or directory it's equal to the number of stands in the database: in my case 3. But for element-value it's twice the number of stands: in my case 6. So all else equal, element-value lookups risk doing twice as much I/O. And all else isn't equal: the URI lookups are less likely to do any I/O at all, because their indexes tend to stay in memory all the time.

We can conclude that while none of the other methods are terribly slow, lookups by collection URI or directory URI are best.

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The implementation of `cts:search` in JavaScript (well, `cts.search`) in the upcoming MarkLogic 8 release, in fact, removes the first parameter and defaults to the equivalent of `cts:search(fn:collection(), $query, $options)`.